# Need to click button twice for event to fire

Tags: javascript, events

In this simple quiz app there is a next-question button. After starting the game by clicking a start-game button the first question with answers show. When clicking the next-question button the first question and answers are still visible, only after clicking a second time the second question appears. In the background though the second question was targeted on the first click, only not visible. Tried several possible solutions but non of them worked.

```
// Methods part of ES6 class Question
displayQuestion() {
     document.querySelector('.question').textContent = this.question
                let i = 0
                let answer = this.answers
            for(let el of answer){
                let html = `<li class="name" id=${i}>${el}</li>`
                document.querySelector('ul').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',html)
                i++ 
            }
 }

getAnswer(id){
        if(id == this.correct) {
            //console.log('Hooray!')
            document.querySelector('.modal1').style.display = "flex";
            document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "block";
           
        }else{
            //console.log('Wrong answer!')
            document.querySelector('.modal2').style.display = "flex";
            document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "block";
        }
        
    }
}

const questions = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5];
let runningQuestion;
let gamePlaying;

init()

document.querySelector('.button1').addEventListener('click', nextQuestion)
function nextQuestion() {

if(gamePlaying && runningQuestion <= questions.length - 1){
    clearAnswers()
    document.querySelector('.button1').textContent = 'Next Question'
    questions[runningQuestion].displayQuestion()
    questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()
    runningQuestion++
}
if(runningQuestion >= questions.length){
    document.querySelector('.button1').textContent = 'Try again!'
    runningQuestion = 0
   }
}

document.querySelector('.answers').addEventListener('click', possibleAnswers)
function possibleAnswers(e){
    console.log(e.target)
    if(e.target && e.target.matches("li.name")){
      let item = e.target.id
        let id = parseInt(item)
        questions[index].getAnswer(id) 
       }
 }


function init() {
   clearAnswers()
   document.querySelector('.question').textContent = ""
   gamePlaying = true
   runningQuestion = 0
   questions[runningQuestion].displayQuestion()
   questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()
}
```

Comment: Hello, there is a specific tool labeled "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet Ctrl-M" which allows us to directly execute your code and witness its behaviour. Feel free to use it whenever you want to ask/answer a javascript question

Comment: What's really happening with this code now can you tell what is the result?

Comment: The result is that when clicking on the right answer it is no longer the right answer cause it is the right answer of the next question. The first click on the button shifts to the next question but not in the UI. The next question only becomes visible after the second click.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess

```js
if(gamePlaying) {
  clearQuestion()
  clearAnswers()
  questions[index].displayQuestion()
  index++
}
```

I think you should increment the index and then call function.

```js
index++
questions[index].displayQuestion()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get the click count, and have a `if (clicks >= 2)` to do the rest

```js
var clicks = 0;

function myFunction() {
  clicks += 1;
  console.log(clicks)
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick = "myFunction()" />
```